# How do I use regrx to parse HTML file and remove all the commented-out text <!-- -->?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, html

I need to parse an HTML file and remove all the lines comment out by `<!--` HTML comments, the file may contain multiple sections of `<!--` and `-->`.

Does somebody know how to use regex to remove the comments between `<!--` and `-->` in an HTML file? The file has multiple lines.

I have about 1000 files to process, and I need to use C#.

Comment: Do you need this by code... why dont you remove just using text editor?

Comment: Just FYI, there are no lines in HTML, not the way you mean.  While the presence of line separators makes it  technically a multiline string, that doesn't change how you deal with it.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
<!--.*?-->
```

With the empty string

And set the option so that the dot matches newlines as well.

In C# this becomes

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, "<!--.*?-->", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: You could write a little program in C# as you say but you could as well use Actual Search & Replace http://www.divlocsoft.com/#find%20and%20replace (shareware)
or http://www.funduc.com/search_replace.htm (commercial). The best is Powergrep but costs a few bucks.

Comment: Am I missing something?  What's the purpose of the `(.)` alternative?  Why don't you just match the comments and replace them with the empty string?

Comment: @Alan I was making it too complicated, the alternative could be omitted indeed. I simplified the answer